# How to analytically solve for the impulse response function of an ODE system?

Tags: differential-equations

I'm quite new to Mathematica, and I'm quite rusty on my differential equations, so I apologise in advance if this is trivial!

I'm trying to use NDSolve to analytically solve a set of differential equations for a compartmental model over time (t) with an input function.  Effectively, I want to figure out the impulse-response function of the following model:

```
 Input  |  System:  (CT = C1 + C2)
        |        
  ____  |  K1   ____    k3   ____   
 | C0 | |----> | C1 | ----> | C2 |  
 |____| |<---- |____| <---- |____|  
        |  k2           k4          
        |
```

where C0(t) is our *known* input function, measured over time (however for this exercise, I'm interested in C0(t) as if it were a Dirac delta function).  We also measure the total of C1(t)+C2(t) = CT(t) (T for total).  Hence, the convolution of our input function C0(t) and the impulse response function, H, generates our measured curve CT(t):

```
CT(t) = (H * Cp)(t)
```

The differential equations are as follows:

```
  dC1(t)/dt = K1*C0(t) - (k2+k3)*C1(t)
  dC2(t)/dt = k3*C1(t) - k4*C2(t)
```

I'm not quite sure how to go about solving this in Mathematica. Ideally, I would like to simplify it to a sum of two exponential functions, as was done [here](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1097/00004647-200106000-00002?url_ver=Z39.88-2003&rfr_id=ori:rid:crossref.org&rfr_dat=cr_pub%20%200pubmed) (page 648, screenshotted below):

[image: Here is the solution I'd like to get with Mathematica]

Is there any way I do this?  I've been trying the following:

```
NDSolve[{C1'[t] == K1*C0[t] - (k2 + k3)*C1[t] + k4*C2[t],
         C2'[t] == k3*C1[t] - k4*C2[t],
         C1[0] == 0,
         C2[0] == 0}, {C1, C2}, {t, 0, 120}]
```

but I get the error:

> NDSolve::underdet: There are more dependent variables, {C0[t],C1[t],C2[t]}, than equations, so the system is underdetermined.

I just want to be able to tell Mathematica that C0 is known, and that I only want C1 and C2, which can be convolved with the input function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is `C0[t]`? BTW for numerical solution you need to provide values for all k's.

Comment: You have 3 dependent variables: C0,C1,C2, but only 2 equations

Comment: Sorry for being unclear!

C0[t] is the input to C1 and C2.  In the experimental setting, I measure it over time and I fit a model to it, which I use as input.  So it's a known and I'm not trying to solve for it.  I'm trying to solve for H(t), the impulse response function, i.e. if C0(t) were a Dirac delta function, what would the function look like.

For fitting the curve, I use nonlinear optimisation: that part is easy. I want to understand how I could use Mathematica to solve for Phi1, Phi2, Theta1 and Theta2 in the attached solution from the article.

Comment: NDSolve can't work with symbolic expressions (or symbolic functions). Maybe this is an indication of a direction `Block[{C0, K1 = 1, k2 = 2, k3 = 3, k4 = 4},
 
 C0[t_] := Exp[-t]; 
 NDSolve[{C1'[t] == K1*C0[t] - (k2 + k3)*C1[t] + k4*C2[t], 
   C2'[t] == k3*C1[t] - k4*C2[t], C1[0] == 0, C2[0] == 0}, {C1, 
   C2}, {t, 0, 120}]
 ]
`

Comment: Riight! I'm barking up the wrong tree with NDSolve then...  I don't actually want to integrate through the function.  I want it to solve for the symbolic impulse response function using Laplace transform.  I think my question is ill-posed.  Thank you so much: that's really helpful!!

Comment: You might try DSolve if you want a symbolic solution.  This gives you a symbolic result, but I have put in a particular C0[t]: ' Block[{C0}, C0[t_] := Exp[-t]; 
 DSolve[{C1'[t] == K1*C0[t] - (k2 + k3)*C1[t] + k4*C2[t], 
   C2'[t] == k3*C1[t] - k4*C2[t], C1[0] == 0, C2[0] == 0}, {C1[t], 
   C2[t]}, t]]'

Comment: And this will give a (messy) solution for any C0[t].  The solution contains integrals that contain c0[t]. `DSolve[{C1'[t] == K1*C0[t] - (k2 + k3)*C1[t] + k4*C2[t], 
  C2'[t] == k3*C1[t] - k4*C2[t], C1[0] == 0, C2[0] == 0}, {C1[t], 
  C2[t]}, t]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DSolve will give you a symbolic result, albeit messy and containing integrals containing the arbitrary function C0[t]:

```
DSolve[{C1'[t] == K1*C0[t] - (k2 + k3)*C1[t] + k4*C2[t],    C2'[t] == k3*C1[t] - k4*C2[t], C1[0] == 0, C2[0] == 0}, {C1[t],    C2[t]}, t]
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for!  Thanks so much!